# Printing a 2D array of JLabels to a GridLayout

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel, grid-layout

I have a maze creator program and want to put it into a gui. My maze is in a 2D array, so i planned to create a 2D array of JLabels in a JPanel and assign each label a color based on whether it's a path or a wall. I can create the 2D array of JLabels and add it to my panel, but when I run it all the JLabels shift right one space so I have a blank space in my top left corner and there is one more column and one less row than there's suppose to be.

Picture of the GUI:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmDvf.png]

Here's my code; I'm not sure what the issue is. I've tried altering the size of the GridLayout, changing how many times my loops run, altering the value of row and col (both are 10 right now), and tried manually creating an extra JLabel in that spot, but no dice.

```
public Maze() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    int row = MazeCreator.r;
    int col = MazeCreator.c;

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));

    JLabel[][] grid= new JLabel[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            grid[i][j] = new JLabel();
            grid[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            //grid[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
            grid[i][j].setOpaque(true);
            super.add(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
    grid[0][0].setBackground(Color.red);
}
```

I can "fix" the too few rows and too many cols issue by subtracting 1 from col and add 1 to row, but that will only create 99 JLabels instead of 100 and, like I said, manually putting in the top left JLabel does not work.

Comment: super.add(grid[i][j]); why?? are you speaking to God??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `super.add()` to add your labels to the panel. And set your panel's layout to `GridLayout` not `JFrame`'s.

```
public Maze() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    int row = MazeCreator.r;
    int col = MazeCreator.c;

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));

    JLabel[][] grid= new JLabel[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            grid[i][j] = new JLabel();
            grid[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            //grid[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
            grid[i][j].setOpaque(true);
            panel.add(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
    grid[0][0].setBackground(Color.red);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The structure of your code is confusing.

```
super.add(....);
```

complicates the code. Why would you use super(...)? You create a panel specifically for the labels to add the label directly to the panel. Don't use super.

Simplfy the logic by create your game panel explicitly and then add the components to that panel:

```
JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(...) );

for (...)
{
    JLabel label = new JLabel(...);
    gamePanel.add( label );
}

add( gamePanel ); // add our game panel to the content pane of the frame.
```

Now your code is more explicit and less error prone.